# Git Log, insert new string only when string is not null

Tags: git, git-bash, git-log

I'm starting learn Git and fastly moved from IDE tools to Git Bash.
It's pretty cool, I love ASCII.

I've try to make my own `git log` alias. Its output looks like this:

`1b3acbf - Fri, 30 Oct 2015 09:37:05 +0400 (4 days ago)
  Merge branch 'dev' into t15017/DriverDetails
  by ViRGiL7`

If I want show tags or branch name, I need to insert a new string:

`1b3acbf - Fri, 30 Oct 2015 09:37:05 +0400 (4 days ago) 
 (HEAD -> t15017/DriverDetails, origin/t15017/DriverDetails)
 Merge branch 'dev' into t15017/DriverDetails
 by ViRGiL7`

But. If commit hasn't any tags or not last in branch, it's look like a empty string:

`1b3acbf - Fri, 30 Oct 2015 09:37:05 +0400 (4 days ago)`

`Merge branch 'dev' into t15017/DriverDetails
 by ViRGiL7`

Can I insert this string only when it's not empty?

I read a `git log` documentation, it contains something about placeholders and `%<(<N>[,trunc|ltrunc|mtrunc])`, but I cant reach any good result with this commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you should use "+" between "%" and placeholder char.

For example: %+d - it's exactly what I want. String with tags shows only when commit have tags.

You should not insert "+" in "%n". That was my mistake.